# Setting up AWS RDS Read Replica on Magento

Tags: magento2, database, aws

My Magento DB hosted on AWS MySQL RDS is running at 100% utilization. I have created a Read Replica so that read query can be served by it. But do not know how to configure it.

Does anyone have any idea on how to set up AWS Read Replica for Magento ?

Comment: Any reference to above request is highly appreciated.

Comment: Someone with any knowledge related to this, please help me!

Comment: Are we talking M1? Or 2.

Comment: @MarcelDumont, it is Magento 1.9.